# ASP.NET Core how to add SuperWebSocketServer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Hi I am having a SuperWebSocketServer class that was working in my asp.net MVC web application.
I am trying to move my project to MVC Core app. And I can seem to make my WebSocketServer running all the time.

Where should I execute my Websocket class?

```
namespace WebApp
{
    public class Websockets
    {
        private static WebSocketServer wsServer;
        public Websockets()
        {
            wsServer = new WebSocketServer();
            int port = 8088;
            wsServer.Setup(port);
            wsServer.NewSessionConnected += NewSessionConnected;
            wsServer.NewMessageReceived += NewMessageReceived;
            wsServer.NewDataReceived += NewDataReceived;
            wsServer.SessionClosed += SessionClosed;
            wsServer.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Server is running on port " + port + ". Press Enter to exit...");
        }
        private static void NewSessionConnected(WebSocketSession session)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NewSession Connected");
        }

        private static void SessionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseReason value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Session Closed");
        }
        private static void NewDataReceived(WebSocketSession session, byte[] data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("New Data Received");
        }

        private static void NewMessageReceived(WebSocketSession session, string data)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("New msg Received");
        }
```

I tried placing it in Program.cs but it doesnt work

```
           namespace WebAppCore
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _ = new Websockets();
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: might be easier to just use SignalR instead?

Comment: I mean the app was working perfectly before, so I dont really want to change anyting.. Just make it work please. I moved from MVC to MVC Core and thats the problem now idk why..

Comment: well, specifically what does "doesn't work" mean? Do you get an error? or some unexpected behaviour?

Comment: My Websocket cant connect to the server. It did before, I spend 12hours today doing it and Im messed up right now

Comment: and the specific error when it can't connect is...? If you get an error, tell us the error, don't just allude to the error, please. Be precise, specific and factual.

Comment: Well It was connecting and instantly disconnecting. Ive changed something now and its undefined

Comment: **what** is undefined, exactly? If it helps, stop describing it and show us.

Comment: Well nvm, its not undefined. It says Connected, then it Disconnects instantly after

Comment: Ok. Have you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-3.1 ? The request pipeline is significantly different in .net core than in framework. I'm not sure you can necessarily just drop this class in and expect it to work, it depends how the internals of the WebSocketServer class are written. Is that something you created yourself, or a 3rd party thing? If the latter, has the maintainer announced any kind of support for .net core?